# One Signal silent notifications in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal

I implemented silent notifications for both platforms. 
Based on OneSignal's documentation, on Android I had to add a class NotificationServiceExtender and in IOS I only had to sent from REST API content_available:true

Normal notifications are working on both platforms, but silent ones in IOS are not triggering:

```
   OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) async {
     print(notification);
}
```

In AppDelegate I made a test if anything is being returned from OneSignal and it seems the data is being returned:

```
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
 print(userInfo)
    }
```

I don't know if there is another method on FLutter from OneSignal that can be triggered or should I make a channel to IOS and retrieve the data. This way it might get complicated.

Also I must mention that Silent Notifications are working on Android devices.

Package:   `onesignal_flutter: ^2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to retrieve directly the received notification.
Therefore I created a Flutter Channel to Native IOS from which I could retrieve the data.

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    var notificationData:NSMutableDictionary
    var isAppInFocus: Bool = false

                   if let custom = userInfo["custom"] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let data = custom["a"] as? NSDictionary {
                            notificationData = data.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary

                            if(data["category"] as? String == "MESSAGESTATUS"){
                                notificationChannel.invokeMethod("getSilentLastSeenMessage", arguments: notificationData)
                            }

                    }}
    }
```

}